# Put a LibGDX project into a Project?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx

I know this question has been asked many times and I still could not find the proper steps to do it. I am using Android Studio. How do I actually put LibGDX project into an Android App project (not putting the Android App project into the LibGDX project)? This is how it should work. When I press a button in the Android app, I could launch my game by setting the game screen. After I finish playing the game, I could go back to the Android App again. Do I need to configure the Gradle file? If that's the case, how do I change it?

This is the problem that I encountered when I import the libGDX modules into the Android App project.

```
Could not find method android() for arguments [build_f3607d3g9oo7ee40quzhms085$_run_closure1@18e45678] on project ':android' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Any extra configurations should be done?

This is my Android Build Gradle file.

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    compileSdkVersion 29
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/robovm/ios/robovm.xml'
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.motivado.game"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}


// called every time gradle gets executed, takes the native dependencies of
// the natives configuration, and extracts them to the proper libs/ folders
// so they get packed with the APK.
task copyAndroidNatives {
    doFirst {
        file("libs/armeabi/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/armeabi-v7a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/arm64-v8a/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86_64/").mkdirs()
        file("libs/x86/").mkdirs()

        configurations.natives.files.each { jar ->
            def outputDir = null
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-arm64-v8a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/arm64-v8a")
            if (jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi-v7a.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi-v7a")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-armeabi.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/armeabi")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86_64.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86_64")
            if(jar.name.endsWith("natives-x86.jar")) outputDir = file("libs/x86")
            if(outputDir != null) {
                copy {
                    from zipTree(jar)
                    into outputDir
                    include "*.so"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

tasks.whenTaskAdded { packageTask ->
    if (packageTask.name.contains("package")) {
        packageTask.dependsOn 'copyAndroidNatives'
    }
}

task run(type: Exec) {
    def path
    def localProperties = project.file("../local.properties")
    if (localProperties.exists()) {
        Properties properties = new Properties()
        localProperties.withInputStream { instr ->
            properties.load(instr)
        }
        def sdkDir = properties.getProperty('sdk.dir')
        if (sdkDir) {
            path = sdkDir
        } else {
            path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
        }
    } else {
        path = "$System.env.ANDROID_HOME"
    }

    def adb = path + "/platform-tools/adb"
    commandLine "$adb", 'shell', 'am', 'start', '-n', 'com.motivado.game/com.motivado.game.AndroidLauncher'
}
```

My main build.gradle

```
buildscript {


    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'


    }
}

allprojects {

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "Motivado Game"
        gdxVersion = '1.9.10'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.8'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
        aiVersion = '1.8.0'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"

    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "android"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share android/build.gradle?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have included the build.gradle. Is this the file you want to see?

Comment: Thanks. And the one in the folder above that?

Comment: Do you mean build.gradle outside of the Android file?

Comment: Yes, please. That one

Comment: I was looking for `project(":android") {  apply plugin: "android"`, which would determine if you can run android builds, but seems that isnt working?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean actually? ```project(":android") { apply plugin: "android"``` is in the main build.gradle I shared. Or do you mean another file?

Comment: That allows you to run Android builds for that project https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html

Comment: Did you check this: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main app **build.gradle**

copy the line `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'`

Move into the imported gdx project **build.gralde**

And the paste the `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` before the **android block**

Scroll down within your gdx project **build.gradle** and comment out the **eclipse** and **idea** blocks too..

Move into the **core build.gradle** and comment out the **eclipse** block also..

Sync and project should build successfully

Comment: It didn't work though as I don't have any eclipse and idea blocks that should be commented out.

Comment: @HolmesQueen, okay, with a fresh project build, i think you should see those in your gradle.